# Facebook tab HTTPS iFrame issue with scrolling

Tags: facebook, iframe, https, scroll

I have an app (https://www.facebook.com/claritycomms/app_483675254991438)

It works fine when using http, however when moving to HTTPS the page no longer scrolls down, it is cut off by the iFrame.

I am not a coder - I built this app using Hype for Mac - the app worked fine for 3 days and now just doesn't :(

Can anyone help please

I have tried changing the setsize parameters in dashboard but the options arent even there

HELP!

I have 1300 fans who want to use the app!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue - https://developers.facebook.com/live_status

Taken from - https://www.facebook.com/feeds/api_status.php

```
{
   "push": {
      "status": "Complete",
      "updated": "2012-07-03T18:50:48-07:00",
      "id": 10156288
   },
   "current": {
      "health": 3,
      "subject": "Issues resizing Page Tab applications",
      "post_time": "2012-07-03T19:19:42-07:00"
   }
}
```

This issue is confirmed and Facebook are handling it.  The fix should be out soon.

Comment: Thanks very much guys - glad to know I'm not going mad!